# How can I add outer rounded corners to a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm looking to add "outer" rounded corners to the selected sidebar item to give the effect that this item is "pouring" into the content well.

In my example below, I'd like the `.top` to have a rounded bottom-right corner with a gray background, along with a similar top-right corner for the `.bottom`.  What do you think?

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and LESS, if that makes it easier.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3YXb2/

Turn this:

[image: rendered]

Into this:

[image]

Markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="top">
            <p>Top</p>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <p>Middle</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <p>Bottom</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:10px;
}
div {
    margin:0;
    margin-right:-4px;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid;
}
.container {
    background-color:gray;
    width:70%;
    height:300px;
}
.sidebar {
    background-color:white;
    width:30%;
    height:300px;
}
.middle {
    background-color:gray;
}
.top,.middle,.bottom {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
}
p {
    padding:40px 0 0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Css3 offers the `border-radius` property. However, please note that this is not available for IE8 or any version lower. There are available *hacks*; but they are just that: hacks.

Usage looks like this:

```
    .sidebar {
        background-color:gray;
        width:30%;
        height:300px;
    }
    .middle {
        background-color:gray;
    }
    .top,.middle,.bottom {
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        display:block;
    }
    .top{
        background: white;
        border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    }
    .bottom{        
        background: white;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }
```

## [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3YXb2/7/)

Comment: Yes, I've been playing with the `.border-top-right-radius(10px);` mixin in bootstrap but I can't figure out how to make the background of the "empty" corner the same as `.middle` in my example.

Comment: @Ryan You would just have a wrapper sitting behind everything - let me try to make you an example using your code.

Comment: @Ryan the latest update should do exactly what you want. If not feel free to let me know, but that should do the trick :)

Comment: nice work!  Slick use of sidebar background.  Will see if I can get this working in production.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, will do.  Just trying to make it work in production first.  Soon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28775/discussion-between-evan-and-ryan)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you're looking for an inverted border radius. Is this what you have in mind?

http://jsfiddle.net/3pW2M/

This will not work if the white area needs to be transparent to show a background image for instance.

```
.top {
    position: relative;
}

.topcorner {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: gray;
}

.topcorner:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 0 0 50px 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes!  This is what I'm looking for.  I'll play around with this to make sure, but this just might work!  Thanks.

Comment: That;s really great answer! Thanks! But what if we need to fill white with some king of gradient or image background?

Answer (score 2):

you may use border-radius of CSS. you can see an online round border generator here:
http://border-radius.com/

Comment: But how do I select the color of the background of the corner?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the background of the corner. It would be the same color as "background-color" if you want you can drop a shadow by box-shadow property.

Comment: So if I add a border radius to the `.top` div above, it will round the corner of the already white div.  But I need the corner to be gray. and the rest white.  Where the gray looks part of the `.middle`.

Comment: you can do a couple of things. If underneath the top div you have a same size div with grey background, the corner will appear as gray. Another option would be making the content as the container div and put other top middle and bottom on top of it. that way, the corner would appear as grey too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that this will be needed for some sort of user interaction, navigation, tabs, ext. So I set it up on a jquery hover function- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/dKsBg/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.top').hover(function () {
    $('.middle').toggleClass('notSelect2');
    $('.bottom').toggleClass('notSelect3');
  });

  $('.middle').hover(function () {
    $('.top').toggleClass('notSelect');
    $('.bottom').toggleClass('notSelect2');
  });

  $('.bottom').hover(function () {
    $('.middle').toggleClass('notSelect');
    $('.top').toggleClass('notSelect3');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS3 *border-radius*.

```
  .top
     {
       border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
       -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
     }

 .bottom
    {
      border-top-right-radius: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    }
```